# Compilation Errors when Compiling Cyanogenmod 2.1

Tags: android, git, compilation, cyanogenmod

Well, this is a long shot. Some coworkers and I are trying to [compile Cyanogenmod 2.1 (eclair) from source](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Compile_CyanogenMod_for_Dream_%26_Sapphire) (yes, the wiki has instructions for 6.x, but it is quite similar to the instructions for 5.x). We're currently trying to sync the git repository using "repo sync". However, some files are missing, and we get this error:

```
error: revision eclair in CyanogenMod/android_external_webkit not found
```

We've tried requesting help on the [Cyanogenmod forums](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com), but so far we've received no response. This has become a rather pressing issue. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how we could compile the eclair branch?

(Again, this is a long shot, but if anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_webkit, there is no eclair branch available for the package you are pulling.

It may just be CyanogenMod yet again failing to support older builds. Sorry.

Comment: It's really unfortunate that they don't support older builds if this is indeed the case.